# Sorting bar chart in Tableau by one category of bars

Tags: visualization, tableau

I have a bar chart that looks like this (truncated for space, orange label obscured for privacy):

[image]

Right now, it is ordered by US state.  The color distinction is for something called "Entity".

Here are the set ups for Marks, Columns, and Rows, and the legend:

[image]

What I'd like to do is sort the order in which these appear, not by state, but rather by the volume measure for the blue Entity ("Industry").  So, in the example above, the states would be re-ordered to NY, NJ, NV, NM.

Is there a way to do this in Tableau? Thanks.

Comment: Uh, OK, why exactly the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you have to create an auxiliary variable

```
If [Entity] == "Industy" THEN [Volume] ELSE 0 END
```

Then you can sort by this. Right click on State then select sort and choose sort by auxiliary variable.